# How to fix Jquery ajax returning 404 not found errro even its working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I'm trying to call post API request which will return a response in JSON format. I was able to do post call to API with the proper response. but when I call it from server side using jQUERY AJAX call I'm getting an error in the network console as get 404 not found. Below is my code

```js
var form = new FormData();
form.append("project", "daynight");
form.append("file", "D:\\Downloads\\GTA.Imaging.Services\\GTA.Imaging.Services.Wrapper.TestApp\\PatternMatchingdata\\CarLife_Launch_Screen.jpg");

var settings = {
  "async": true,
  "crossDomain": true,
  "url": "http://10.90.232.146:9986/getcontext/",
  "method": "POST",
  "processData": false,
  "contentType": false,
  "mimeType": "multipart/form-data",
  "data": form
};
var dataJson = JSON.stringify(settings);

$.ajax(dataJson).done(function(response) {
  console.log(response);
});
```

[image]

I know similar questions have been answered all the solution was saying formatting sending data, I have done json formatting of text. What am I doing wrong? Thanks , let me know any more questions needed to be answered

Comment: The problem is entirely because, for some reason, you are encoding the settings object to JSON. Do not do that. Just provide it directly to the AJAX call. eg `$.ajax(settings)`. Voting to close as a syntax error. Also be careful that you don't end up with CORS issues if you're sending this as a cross domain request

Comment: Please check if its a CORS issue.

Comment: @AlekhyaSatya you can see from the console that it's not currently.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I tried with $.ajax(settings) still I was getting the same error, I was facing CORS issue earlier I installed CORS changer plugin to avoid that is there a way to fix this issue. thanks

Comment: @AlekhyaSatya check my above comment

Comment: If you're getting a CORS issue then that is a completely different problem which you need to fix on the receiving server. I can tell you with 100% certainty though, that JSON encoding the settings is only going to cause problems

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I understand. If I don't use CORS plugin I end up getting error as below Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://10.90.232.146:9986/getcontext/' from origin 'http://localhost:5501' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.